# Bootstrap 4 : two image overlay

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need some help. I am supposed to do it, like in the screenshot. I tried to put the img (`z-index: 5` over the colored line (`z-index: 2`).

[image]

[My jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cyphos/61tvq5ap/30/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to code by looking at the picture.. Here is what I made.. Take a look at the code. I think I made what you were tryin to.. But even if it doesn't, then let me know..

```css
#image {
 background: url('http://www.lefrancais.eu/files/2013/05/signature-contrat.jpg')
  no-repeat center/cover;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 95vh;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: -1;
}
#image-2 {
 margin-top: -100px;
 margin-bottom: -3.6%;
}
#image-2 img {
 height: 100px;
 width: 170px;
}
footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 5vh;
 background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="image">
        <h2 class="display-6 text-center mt-5 text-light">Découvrez tous nos
          programmes près de chez vous</h2>

      </div>
      <div id="image-2">
        <img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/logo-de-pomme_318-40184.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks but the img apple don't really align on bottom when i reduce the window for responsive.

Comment: For responsiveness, try applying some media queries to the img apple... I guess it could work...